# Are nullable types perfect for my situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000

Recently converted my ASP.NET project from 1.1 to 3.5. Hooray! Currently developing a form which has a handful of optional fields. Normally, I'd go through in my code, adding tons of if statements, checking for empty field, and setting value to 0 if so. So, I'm wondering if it would be best to instead, declare private, nullable variables for each of these fields, then add these as parameters for my database update? Using MSSQLS 2000, already set the corresponding fields to allow nulls.

To clarify: The web form has fields for dollar amounts. The default value on the inputs is 0, but if the user deletes one of those 0's, leaving the field empty then submits the form, an exception will be thrown at Convert.ToDecimal(MoneyField.Text) in the argument list of the method that submits all this to the database. Is there a cleaner way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unusual that you would have *that* many fields that are truly nullable, but *if* you need to describe "no value" separately to any magic domain value of (for example) an `int`, then yes: `Nullable<T>` may help. Note that you must manually translate from `null` to `DbNull.Value` at the data-layer, as `null` on a `SqlParameter` means "don't send this parameter", *not* "send the value `null`" (if you see the distinction).

Comment: I don't know if it's _that many_; form has 21 fields, 9 of them are optional, dollar amounts. So, as an argument, I'm trying: Convert.ToDecimal(MoneyField.Text). Now, if nothing was entered into that field, the conversion fails. So I'm trying to find the cleanest way to allow that argument to be null, so I can pass that null onto the database.

Comment: Build the required insert fileds on those that were entered. Build a list of fields to insert and forget about hte rest.

Comment: I haven't yet dealt with lists, so I'll have to do some reading to see if that's a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is mix up between field validation and Nullable Type here...unless of course you have a some type ...say `DateTime` and want that to be null...which would not be possible **unless usage** of Nullable Type.

If that is the case then ...yes..Nullable types are the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, sounds like a plan.

You'd have to change a couple of calls though

```
static class NConv
{
    static T? ToNullable<T>(string str) where T : struct
    {
        return (T?)(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? default(T?) : Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T)));
    }

    static void HowTo()
    {
        double? myBonus = NConv.ToNullable<double>(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically build your sql based upon the fields supplied.